# php-5.3.17 install memcached memcache extension

Tags: php, memcached

centos 6.3 , php-5.3.17, memcached extesion is memcached-2.1.0.tar.gz;
And then:

```
tar -zxvf memcached-2.1.0.tar.gz
cd memcached-2.1.0
./configure --with-php-config=/usr/local/php/bin/php-config
 make
```

And have error, like this:
[image]

Why??

Comment: and I installed limbmemcached， by yum

Answer (score 0):

On Centos 6.3, you can save yourself a lot of time and effort by using a ready-made RPM:

http://pkgs.org/download/php-pecl-memcached

RPMs are also available for up-to-date versions of PHP, MySQL, etc, if you're not already using them.

If you decide to add the Remi repository to your `yum` configuration, you can add the following line to `/etc/yum.repos.d/remi.repo` to select the packages you need:

```
includepkgs=mysql* php*
```

Comment: I can't find /etc/yum.repos.d/remi.repo in /etc/yum.repos.d

Comment: It won't be there unless you install it:
`curl -O http://rpms.famillecollet.com/enterprise/remi-release-6.rpm`
`rpm -ivh remi-release-6.rpm`

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you'll need to install [libmemcached](http://libmemcached.org/libMemcached.html), as it's dependency for pecl-memcached

```
sh ~> curl -O https://launchpad.net/libmemcached/1.0/1.0.11/+download/libmemcached-1.0.11.tar.gz
sh ~> tar zvxf libmemcached-1.0.11.tar.gz
sh ~> cd libmemcached-1.0.11
sh ~> ./configure
sh ~> make
sh ~> sudo make install
```

Also, use the `phpize` before configuring PECL source files

```
sh ~> tar zxvf memcached-2.1.0.tar.gz
sh ~> cd memcached-2.1.0
sh ~> phpize
sh ~> ./configure --with-php-config=/usr/local/php/bin/php-config
sh ~> make 
sh ~> make test
sh ~> sudo make install
```

Comment: And, I want tu install libmemcached-1.0.11.tar.gz, when i use "make" command , it's alse has error, like this:                                                                            cc1plus: warnings being treated as errors
In file included from libmemcached/csl/parser.yy:59:
libmemcached/csl/scanner.l:50: error: unknown option after '#pragma GCC diagnostic' kind
make[1]: *** [libmemcached/csl/libmemcached_libmemcached_la-parser.lo] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/usr/local/src/libmemcached-1.0.11'
make: *** [all] Error 2

Comment: Looks like that was a bug related to GCC introduced in 1.0.11. [details here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/libmemcached/+bug/1053287). You can try building previous version [1.0.10](https://launchpad.net/libmemcached/1.0/1.0.10), or wait for patch/fix